# Dependency injection in django Views

Tags: python, django, dependency-injection

I want to use dependency injection for my django project. For that I'm trying [pinject](https://github.com/google/pinject) package. Like in ASP.NET, all the dependencies are given in the constructor, and that's very nice because it's easy to test. I would also like to archive something similar in my django project.

I have a simple View:

```py
class MySimpleView(View):
    def __init__(self, dependency1, dependency2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
```

A place where I define the bindings

```py
# di.py
class AppBindingSpec(pinject.BindingSpec):
    def configure(self, bind):
        # do the bindings here


obj_graph = pinject.new_object_graph(binding_specs=[AppBindingSpec()])
```

And I expected to use it like this.

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('path/to/my/view', obj_graph.provide(MySimpleView).as_view()),
]
```

But unfortunately, django does not allow the `.as_view()` to be called from an instance.

Is there any simple way to inject the dependencies into my view so I can easily mock and test?

Comment: I don't think your approach will work. A Django view is actually a function (not an instance) and `as_view()` is a class-only method on a CBV that returns a view function. I don't see an immediate solution, since pinject injects dependencies into class instances.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with dependency injection ? This looks like an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Taek I would like to make the views easy to test. I'm kind of new to django, but I was hopping to achieve something similar to Asp.Net. To reformulate the question: How to write the views so that it's easy to mock and test?

Comment: I don't know anything about pinject, or indeed much about dependency injection at all (it's rarely a thing in Python), but in fact Django's CBVs actually pass all arguments received from `as_view` into the init method, where they are stored as instance attributes. So potentially you could pass your dependencies in directly from the urls.py.

Comment: @EmilTerman I had the same issue when starting django comming from another framework, try to forget about your ASP.Net knowledge.
Testing views in django is faily easy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial05/#testing-our-new-view

If you have a question about a specific view you'd like to test make a new one

Comment: @Taek, thank you for the link. But those are not Unit Tests. I just want to mock the dependencies and check if the view does what I need it to do. [Concrete example] My view calls some a business rule (a dependency), and I would like to test if the view returns the right http status if an exception was thrown inside of it. Normally, I would mock that dependency.

Comment: Why not put the business rule in a function/method and simply mock it ?

Comment: @Taek, what exactly do you mean? I've got a business rule `CamerasAutodetectBlRul`. It has a method `execute()`. It is already in a method. I may be missing something, but how do I 'simply' mock it? At the moment, the view instantiates this class and calls the method `execute()`. I can't see any straightforward way of mocking that method. My idea was to pass this business rule object as a constructor parameter, so I can pass a mocked object when testing.

Comment: I'm not certain without more of the code but this should be what you need : https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to provide yourself with an easy and safe way to '*mock and test*', then you are probably better of using the [mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) provided by `unittest` (which by the way is also a lot like mocking in .NET). With this, you can do something like this:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from django.tests import TestCase

class MySimpleViewTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch('module_name.dependency2')
    @patch('module_name.dependency1.specific_method_or_attribute')
    def test_something_about_mysimpleview(self, mock_dependency1, mock_dependency2):
        mock_dependency1.return_value = Mock(some_attribute="foo", some_method.return_value="bar")
        mock_dependency2.return_value = 42

        # do your testing of MySimpleView
```

Now, when the test runs, `mock` will replace whatever `module_name.dependency1.specific_method_or_attribute` and `module_name.dependency2` was with mock objects. So, when `module_name.dependency2()` is run, it will return `42`, while `specific_method()` will return a `Mock`object with an attribute with the value `"foo"` and a method `some_method()` that returns `"bar"`.

You can use this to mock functions, classes or even modules.

Comment: Yeah, while reading @Taek's suggestions, I made the same conclusion